# Copying large text from one RichTextBox to another slows down the UI

Tags: c#, performance, winforms, asynchronous

I'm trying to synchronize the text of two RichTextBoxes via `TextChanged`. Unfortunately, the UI starts to slow down when editing large text (freezes are already noticeable at 250000 characters).

Here is my code:

```
async void rtb1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            rtb2.Text = rtb1.Text;
        }));
    });
}
```

I expected that the text in the second `RichTextBox` would appear some milliseconds later after editing the text in the first one without slowdowns.

I count on your support.

Comment: Starting a Task there to just invoke back to the UI Thread has no meaning, it just adds overhead -- There's not much you can do with this Control, it's not exactly built to handle that much text. Some more *advanced features* (as full text justification) have already been cut off to improve performance (and avoid some glitches) but not much else. You could try to work with the underlying [EDITSTREAM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/richedit/ns-richedit-editstream), but things may get quite complicated

Comment: You may want to test [FastColoredTextBox](https://github.com/PavelTorgashov/FastColoredTextBox/tree/master/FastColoredTextBox) instead. This is written to handle large amount of text

Answer (score 0):

The [`BeginInvoke`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.begininvoke) invokes the action on the UI thread, so the `Task.Factory.StartNew`+`BeginInvoke` endeavor accomplishes nothing. When there are performance problems with UI controls, multithreading is not a solution. You have to solve the problem staying in the realm of the UI thread. Honestly I don't know if there is a solution to your problem. Maybe the `RichTextBox` control is simply not capable of dealing efficiently with so long texts.